# How to write RSpec for method that raises error

Tags: ruby, rspec

Hi I want to write RSpec test for the method below

```
Class A
 def test
   val = nil
   raise "invalid" unless var
  end
end
```

Can someone please help me, how can I write RSpec for `#test` method when `val` is `nil`

Comment: Rspec docs are very helpful with lots of examples: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```rb
describe A do
  let(:a) { A.new }
 
  describe '#test' do
    it "raises an error" do
      expect { a.test }.to raise_error("invalid")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting. Why pass the string to `describe`? If you pass the class, you can use [`subject`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject) and `described_class`. https://pastebin.com/dsFdaqMc

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Change the `describe A`. I haven't written a single line of RSpec in the last two years and therefore forgot that I can pass the class directly. Regarding `subject` and `described_class`, I don't like them because without looking at the definition at the top of your file it is not always clear what they referer to. I think it is clearer and easier to read and understand when being more explicit.

Comment: To each his own, I guess :) I myself don't use plain subject, I name it: `subject(:a) { A.new }`. But `described_class`, I like it a lot. It enables generic specs (`shared_examples_for`, etc.) In my experience, it does not hinder reading too much.